# Union ALL query failed in VBA but ok in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, excel, vba, union

I have a very long query which contains 10 Union ALL statements, the whole query was fine in Oracle SQL Developer but failed in Excel VBA.

I tested the VBA code by removing the Union ALL statements one by one, it worked fine with any one of the Union ALL statements. When the query has two or more Union ALL, it failed again.

Does Excel VBA manipulate the query string during execution ?

Comment: keep in mind one thing that while using `Union All` or `union` columns  count must be same in all queries.

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: verify if you don´t miss spaces on copy to run on excel.

Comment: If you debug.print the SQL statement can you run it directly in Oracle?

Comment: It's quite possible that `VBA` applies its own limits on query and result-set sizes.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The error is Run-time error "1004".

Comment: I just did some more testing. The original query is created in Excel VBA as a string variable which was 65129 chars long , the query is then exported into a txt file, opened in notepad, cut and pasted in Oracle SQL developer and returned results as expected.  However Run-time error 1004 appeared when query directed in VBA (via ODBC connection).  I then try to eliminated some of the query statements, it worked when the query is 30174 char long but failed at 35349 char. The number of union all in fact does not caused the problem.  Could it be due to limitations of Excel with long strings ?

Comment: According to MSDN : "_A variable-length string can contain up to approximately 2 billion (2^31) characters._"
So it's not about Excel and string I think. Do you have an integer in your code which manages the chars ? Because I was thinking about the max value of an integer (32 767)

Comment: The number of chars for the query was counted in Notepad++ after exported from VBA. Shorter variations of the original query worked ok hence the VBA code is fine. Perhaps it got something to do with the ODBC connection to the server ie if the connection timed out before the query was fully fed to the server due to its length?

Answer (score 2):

Ok .. after many more hours of googling I sort of have an answer now:

http://fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm

"NOTE: the maximum length of an SQL statement in VBA is 32,768 characters!)"

Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: Good to know :) Surprisingly related to integer max value.